# Access values of simpleXML object when values themselves are also simpleXML objects

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML response from a third party server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Search type="upcDetails">
<Error>
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorMessage>SUCCESS</ErrorMessage>
</Error>
<Product>
  <Name><![CDATA[CGC UltraLight Gypsum 4'x8'x1/2"]]></Name>
  <ProductId><![CDATA[1000686028]]></ProductId>
  <storeAvailabilityText><![CDATA[Mississauga Britannia Store Qty: 806]]></storeAvailabilityText>
   <OriginalPrice><![CDATA[6.49 ]]></OriginalPrice><UOM><![CDATA[EA]]></UOM>
   <IsOnline><![CDATA[true]]></IsOnline>
</Product>
</Search>
```

Then I do `$simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($response);` and then print_r($simpleXML) and the response I get is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => upcDetails ) [Error] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ErrorCode] => 0 [ErrorMessage] => SUCCESS ) [Product] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ProductId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [storeAvailabilityText] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [OriginalPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [UOM] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [IsOnline] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) )
```

How do I access the values of for example `[ProductId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )` when the value itself is another SimpleXMLobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xml->Product->ProductId;
```

Comment: o man... what a stupid mistake.. I didnt see that <ProductId> was nested in <Product>....

Answer (score 1):

[`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implements the [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method, so if you use `$simpleXML->Product->ProductId` in a string context, or cast it explicitly, you'll get the child text the element.

#### Example:

```
var_dump((string) $simpleXML->Product->ProductId);
```

#### Output:

```
string(10) "1000686028"
```

Comment: Yeah, I made a silly oversight. I was trying $simpleXML->ProductId. Didn't notice the ProductId was nested inside Product. @Ram Sharma pointed it out and I realized right away. Thanks for your help as well